# Need Local Database for Flutter Web Application

Tags: database, flutter-web

I have tried using SEMBAST as local database but it works only for android or IOS Not Web, but i have a requirement to use local database to store all my UI data and reuse it locally , so please help to solve it .

Below is my flutter doctor log :

```
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.14.2-pre.54, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale en-IN)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IndexedDB is the main solution for local database in the browser. You can use that or any solution on top of that (hive, idb_shim/idb_sqflite).

Comment: As a side note, sembast has web support now using [sembast_web](https://pub.dev/packages/sembast_web)